# NoClassDefFoundError DecimalFormat

Tags: java

Im trying to make a new program witch does calculate some numbers. And i use DecimalFormat in it. I started doing it in another computer. It was work fine before but when i switch the computer ,i started getting this error.

I already import:

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
```

When i star the program it works fine until i use an object which use DecimalFormak. Then i get this error.

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/ibm/icu/text/DecimalFormat

An example for the cod:

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat("0.00");
double number= Double.parseDouble(detay.get(0)); //detay.get(0) is a number like (123.456)
String number1= decimalFormat.format(number);
textField_1.setText(number1+"");
```

Note:After the comments i tryed this but nothing changed.

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

Comment: can you post the entire code (including the import statements)?

Comment: The package the error refers to is not the default java package for DecimalFormat.
com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat != java.text.DecimalFormat
Therefore java can't find it, as this lib may not be present on that machine. Try to refer full qualified in your code like '= new java.text.DecimalFormat();'

Comment: @aeberhart it is realy big code to share all. What part you want to see ?

Comment: @roediGERhard i tryed but nothing changed

Comment: Somewhere in your code you reference com.ibm.icu.text. This package must be available for the compiler but not to the runtime when you're running your code.

Comment: Another possible cause is that you are running an old .class file (so maybe your changed to java.text in the editor but for some reason still run the old .class containing the IBM package)

Answer (score 1):

You import `java.text.DecimalFormat;` but you are using `com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat` according to the exception.

Try with

```
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new java.text.DecimalFormat("0.00");
```

If this works you have something strange in the imports.

Comment: i was using this :com.ibm.icu.text.DecimalFormat in my old pc. But when i change the pc i get error becouse of this so itryed this :java.text.DecimalFormat;. But now i get the error what i said. And tryed what you said but nothing changed.